# How to pass props to a component inside the relay createContainer()?

Tags: relay

How can I pass props to the component that's inside the createContainer() function?

From what I see, createContainer() does not seem capable of passing props to the component.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain what you mean by "createContainer() does not seem capable of passing props to the component"?

Answer (score 0):

For example, when you have:

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  const myProp = 'one prop';
  return {
    my-prop: myProp,
  };
}, App);
```

The first argument of **createContainer** receives a function where you can declare your props. The second argument is the component you want to wrap.

For more information, take a look in the *createContainer* itself:

https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/blob/devel/packages/react-meteor-data/createContainer.jsx